# python create a dictionary with specific key name and assign values to it from a text file with multiple lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Hi I want to create a dictionary with my own key names and assign values to it from a text file that has multiple lines. Each entry consists of a restaurant name and food category. every entry is separated by a line.

I have a text file that contains these values:

```
Macdonalds
fast food

Sushiro 
japanese food
```

I want the dictionary to appear like this

```
{ 'Restaurant name': [Macdonalds, Sushiro], 'Food category': [fast food, japanese food] }
```

These are the codes that I have tried:

```
with open("food.txt", "r") as file:
    dict = {}
    for line in file:
        line = line.split()
        if not line:
            continue
        dict[line[0]] = line[1:]
print(dict)
```

which displays this

```
{ 'macdonalds': [ ], 'fast': ['food'] }
```

Thank you!! I am new to Python so really appreciate your help

Comment: What have you tried so far and what isn't working?

Comment: @marg, are you going to have a line of separation between each restaurant-food entry?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf yes. Each entry in the file is a restaurant name and food category, so every entry is separated by a line

Comment: @AirSquid so far I've only managed to get a dictionary that displays this
{ 'macdonalds': [ ], 'fast': ['food'] }

Comment: That data structure is code smell

Comment: Mad Physicist hints that you should use a list of `Restaurant` objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there are newlines separating restaurant-food entries, and assuming you have some quotes around those strings in your desired dictionary, you can do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Initialize a dictionary
my_dict = {
    "Restaurant name": [],
    "Food category": []
}

# Open up a file named "input.txt"
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    # Read in a restaurant name
    restaurant_name = f.readline().strip()
    
    # Keep looping while there are more restaurants
    while restaurant_name:
        # Add the restaurant to our dictionary
        my_dict["Restaurant name"].append(restaurant_name)
        # Read in the food category and add it to our dictionary
        my_dict["Food category"].append(f.readline().strip())
        # Read in that blank line
        f.readline()
        # Read in the next restaurant name; will return none if there
        # aren't any more lines, causing the loop to stop.
        restaurant_name = f.readline().strip()

print(my_dict)
```

That will generate a dictionary at the end that looks like this:

```
{'Restaurant name': ['Macdonalds', 'Sushiro'], 'Food category': ['fast food', 'japanese food']}
```

Answer (score 0):

**if flag is 'food'**

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
buffer = {'Restaurant name':[], 'Food category':[]}
while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    if line == '\n':
        continue
    line = line.replace('\n', '')
    if 'food' in line:
        buffer['Food category'].append(line)
    else:
        buffer['Restaurant name'].append(line)

print(buffer)
```

result is

```
{'Restaurant name': ['Macdonalds', 'Sushiro'], 'Food category': ['fast food', 'japanese food']}
```